# SQL Syntax using MAX in nested Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m looking for the syntax to return only products whose latest **process date** had their **transactions** status as “Paid”

So something like…

```
    Select Products
    From Table 1
    Where MAX(Process_date) … *(as I don’t know what to do here)*
    AND Transactions IN ‘Paid’
    AND product_key = z.product_key
```

...This THEN will be used as a nested query to attach with another who has Z as its indicator.. a little help?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
Select t.*
From Table1 t
where t.process_date = (select max(t2.process_date)
                        from t t2
                        where t2.product_key = t.product_key
                       ) and
      t.status = 'Paid';
```

If you just want the product key, then there is a fun method using aggregation:

```
select product_key
from table1
group by product_key
having max(process_date) = max(case when t.status = 'Paid' then process_date end);
```

This tests if the largest `process_date` is the `process_date` on a paid status.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this is what i needed